# Laravel Undefined property: stdClass::multimedia

Tags: laravel

Tengo una consulta, tengo un error a la hora de retornar una llave foranea en la vista.

Controlador (la funcion que estoy utilizando)

```
public function busqueda()
{
   $user = Auth::user();
   $propiedad = DB::table('propiedad')
          ->join ('multimedia', 'multimedia.id_propiedad', '=', 'propiedad.id_propiedad' )
          ->orderBy('propiedad.id_propiedad', 'asc')
          ->get();

   return view('inquilino/propiedades', compact('user', 'propiedad'));
}
```

Vista

```
@if($propiedad->count())
   @foreach($propiedad as $key=>$prop)

   <tr>
      <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
      <td>{{$prop->multimedia->nombre}}</td> -->Aqui me sale el error
      <td>{{$prop->ciudad}}</td>
      <td>{{$prop->zona}}</td>
      <td>{{$prop->descripcion}}</td>
      <td>{{$prop->costo}}</td>
      <!--<td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{action('InquilinoController@busqueda_prop', $prop->id_propiedad)}}" ></a></td>-->
   </tr>

   @endforeach
@else
@endif
```

El error me sale en la vista, no tengo mucha experiencia en laravel, me gustaria poder hacer un listado de 2 tablas, segun investigue para hacer esto necesita hacer uso de los modelos pero en mi caso no estoy utilizando eloquent y me gustaria saber como se realizaria utilizado Query Builder.

Comment: No tienes un objeto Collection, tienes un array y deberías acceder $prop["multimedia"];